# Filling holes easy/quick method

Tags: mesh

I have the mesh shown in the image and want to fill the holes. If I select each edge and use F then not all of the edges are joined all the way around.

Is there an easier or better method to complete this task?

thank you

[image]

Fill Holes result as per first suggestion (not sure how to add image to a comment0

[image]

[image]

Should also say I am using 2.8

Comment: select them then hit space and type in bridge edge loops

Comment: Brilliant - thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure how to give you the answer or upvote or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to edit mode, select your mesh and Press space and type fill holes and select the option and then go to the left panel and change the sides option to 5 or 10 (change it if it doesnt do anyting)

Comment: Thank you Michael. It creates the faces at 8 iterations but doubles up on the face in the middle and does not create the verts/edges in place. So two large faces. Sorry not sure how to add an image to a comment so added it to the orginal post - thank you

Comment: just delete the middle face and then triangulete the other face with ctrl+t and then untriangule with alt+j you are done, after that remove doubles just in case. i dont know if this shotcuts changed in 2.8, also mark the question as solved in the button below the vote down button

Comment: thank you again for your time. The result is posted above. As you can see it does not solve it but I will keep looking. Thank you